# Balancing algorithm for something like chat room

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm that would be used for something like chatroom balancing that would meet the following rules:

- there is no limit on the number of chat rooms
- chat rooms are of a fixed size (10 max)
- chat rooms must meet a minimum number (3)
- you can join multiple chat rooms
- if a room can't be found, there is a waiting list
- once in a room, the system can't change the user (user could leave and rejoin)
- the priority is to have full rooms while having minimal people waiting.

So initially the first room should be full and then people placed in waiting room until a second room can be opened. Once people start leaving and new people join we should try to keep tables full while still reducing wait times.

Comment: I doubt that an algorithm that for that specific requirements already exists. So you need to look for similar problems and/or come up with your own idea / implementation. So we would be very interested in your ideas / research / code and any problems you encounter.

Comment: "the priority is to have full rooms while having minimal people waiting" - Those 2 goals are probably contradictory.  Or at least, they are unless you specify which goal takes priority over the other.

Comment: What happens when someone leaves from a chatroom of 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see where the challenge is.

Send incoming people to the chat rooms as long as there is room. Otherwise, push to a FIFO queue to minimize the waiting time.

The only choice that I see is when not all rooms are full and you have several options. In this case, choose the less crowded room, to reduce the chances that it empties.